# ClassNotFoundException com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement

Tags: android, admob

I upgraded google play services to 11.0.4 in my android app and I started getting this warning even though I am NOT integrating with firebase:

```
W/Ads: Invoke Firebase method getInstance error.
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement" 
     on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.twelvelouisiana.android.trippod.electric-2/base.apk", 
     zip file "/data/app/com.twelvelouisiana.android.trippod.electric-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", 
     zip file "/data/app/com.twelvelouisiana.android.trippod.electric-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", 
     zip file "/data/app/com.twelvelouisiana.android.trippod.electric-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk",
     zip file "/data/app/com.twelvelouisiana.android.trippod.electric-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", 
     zip file "/data/app/com.twelvelouisiana.android.trippod.electric-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", 
     zip file "/data/app/com.twelvelouisiana.android.trippod.electric-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk",
     zip file "/data/app/com.twelvelouisiana.android.trippod.electric-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", 
     zip file "/data/app/com.twelvelouisiana.android.trippod.electric-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", 
     zip file "/data/app/com.twelvelouisiana.android.trippod.electric-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", 
     zip file "/data/app/com.twelvelouisiana.android.trippod.electric-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", 
     zip file "/data/app/com.twelvelouisiana.android.trippod.electric-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],
     nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.twelvelouisiana.android.trippod.electric-2/lib/x86_64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
     at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.scionintegration.b.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:166)
     at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.scionintegration.b.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:151)
     at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.scionintegration.b.f(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:42)
     at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.request.c.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:26)
     at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.b.run(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:4)
     at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.af.call(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:3)
     at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.ag.run(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:3)
     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423)
     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement
     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
     at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
     at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
```

Is there something I need to disable in my code?

```
MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.banner_ad_app_id));
    AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Comment: [Please check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45402863/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-failed-resolution-of-lio-socket-client-iooptio),may help you

Comment: Did you google the error message? What did you find?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Mobile Ads SDK team was able to reproduce and fix the error. It will be corrected in a future release.
See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!search/appMeasurement/google-admob-ads-sdk/9Cukd02En9o/ELCZfzjUCQAJ

Answer (score 0):

Go to **setting > Build Execution Deployment > disable instant run**.

Comment: The issue is not resolved. I created a post in the AdMob SDK group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!search/appMeasurement/google-admob-ads-sdk/9Cukd02En9o/ELCZfzjUCQAJ